# Хорошей ли считается практикой, обновлять данные в связанных таблиц, через триггеры?

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite

Хорошей ли считается практикой, обновлять данные в связанных (FOREIGN KEY- внешним ключом) таблиц , через триггеры?

Есть два варианта обновления данных:

**1**.*через триггеры*

**2**.*через внешний ключ добавив параметр* -  ON UPDATE CASCADE

Какой вариант считается более предпочтительнее?

**Примечание**: Добавление и обновления данных, будет происходить только в родительской таблице. Но читать мы эти данные будем из дочерней таблицы, которая связанна с родительской. И для того что бы мы получили актуальные данные из дочерней таблицы, мы должны их как то 'синхронно' или почти синхронно обновлять из родительской таблицы. В связи с этим, я рассматриваю два варианта, которые описал выше.

Answer (score 1):

Через внешний ключ можно лишь контролировать целостность таблиц. Т.е. ForeignKeyId всегда будет указывать запись в родительской таблице. Единственные данные, которые вы можете обновить, это этот самый Id с помощью параметра ON UPDATE CASCADE

Триггер даёт вам гибкость. Например, если возможно цикличное удаление, то каскадное удаление создать нельзя в принципе и тут в любом случае только триггер вас спасёт.

Минус триггеров в том, что зачастую их в базе не видно и сложно понять, например, почему при удалении возникает ошибка в какой-нибудь таблице с которой, вы, вроде бы, в данный момент не работаете.